# How can I find the oblique asymptote of $y=\frac{x^3-2x^2+x-1}{x^2+1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

Does any one has any idea about how to find the oblique asymptote of this curve?

$$y=\dfrac{x^3-2x^2+x-1}{x^2+1}$$

[(original problem image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLrUv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$  \left(   x^{3}  - 2 x^{2}  +  x  - 1 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  - 2 \right) } +  \left( 1  \right)  $$
so your fraction is
$$ x-2 + \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} $$
and, for large $|x|,$   ......

Answer (score 1):

Polynomial division can be written as $$f(x)=d(x)q(x)+r(x),$$ where $f(x)$ is the polynomial, $d(x)$ is the divisor, $q(x)$ is the quotient, and $r(x)$ is the remainder.  Rearranging the equation, we can write $$\frac{f(x)}{d(x)}=q(x)+\frac{r(x)}{d(x)},$$
where $\dfrac{f(x)}{d(x)}$ is now a rational function and $q(x)$ is the asymptote provided that $r(x)\neq0$.

Your polynomial division should result in the equation $$x^3-2x^2+x-1=(x^2+1)(x-2)+1\implies\frac{x^3-2x^2+x-1}{x^2+1}=\underbrace{x-2}_\text{asymptote}+\frac1{x^2+1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

If

$\begin{array}\\
f(x) 
&= \dfrac{x^3-2x^2+x-1}{x^2+1}\\
\text{then}\\
f(x)-x
&= \dfrac{x^3-2x^2+x-1}{x^2+1}-x\\
&= \dfrac{x^3-2x^2+x-x^3-x}{x^2+1}\\
&= \dfrac{-2x^2}{x^2+1}\\
\text{and}\\
f(x)-x+2
&= \dfrac{-2x^2}{x^2+1}+2\\
&= \dfrac{-2x^2+2x^2+2}{x^2+1}\\
&= \dfrac{2}{x^2+1}\\
\end{array}
$

so
$f(x)
=x-2+\dfrac{2}{x^2+1}
$.

Answer (score 1):

Note

$$\frac{x^3-2x^2+x-1}{x^2+1}= x-2 +\frac1{x^2+1}$$

which indicates that the oblique asymptote is $x-2$.